# MSVC error C2280 (attempting to reference a deleted function) that works with all other compilers

Tags: c++, visual-c++

The following code fails to compile with all recent versions of MSVC but succeeds with all recent versions of GCC and Clang:

```
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
#include <list>

using namespace std;

struct A
{
    int a;
};

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
  vector<list<unique_ptr<A>>> v;
  v.emplace_back();
}
```

With all recent versions of MSVC, the `emplace_back()` call triggers compiler error C2280 "attempting to reference a deleted function".

Is this code actually in error?  I understand it to be constructing an empty list in-place at the end of vector v.

If it *is* in error, how should I construct this list and place it in the vector?  I've already tried explicitly constructing an empty list and moving it into the vector, with the same C2280 result:

```
list<unique_ptr<A>> elem;
v.push_back(move(elem));
```

Comment: Compiling to what standard?

Comment: c++17, e.g. https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/5E6qzc

Comment: Error looks like it's still making a copy. `emplace_back()` shouldn't be making a copy, but I don't know the actual standard wording on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this is an example of a more general problem that was acknowledged by the primary implementer of the MSVC standard library in [this r/cpp thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/cpp/comments/6q94ai/chromium_windows_builds_now_use_clangcl_by_default/dkwdd8l?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3). The problem applies to all `container<container<unique_ptr>>` constructs, where the inner container is a node-based container (like `list` or `map`). He suggests an unpleasant workaround:

> There is, however, a workaround possible for your code. If you wrap
> your inner `container<unique_ptr<whatever>>` in a class that manually
> deletes its copies and defaults its moves (basically telling the
> compiler what the Standard should do, but doesn't), then
> `vector<YourWrapper<container<unique_ptr<whatever>>>>` will behave
> properly (and you'll get moves during reallocation).

In my own case, I reluctantly replaced `unique_ptr` with `shared_ptr`.  It was not in performance-critical code, so I was willing to accept the technically unnecessary performance hit.